# IF Statement with more than one true condition

Tags: c#

So I want my program to do a certain thing if two or more boolean conditions in a list are true. Using Or operators will only get me one or more, and I'm not sure how to program this.

Comment: A loop and a counter of the number of `true` values you've seen? Linq's `Count()`?

Comment: What have you tried? What errors are you getting, have you tried searching for an answer outside of just asking?

Comment: Honestly, not a lot - all my googling produced basic guides on how to write If statements. I'm not getting errors per se as it's not a bug, it's just "I don't know how to do this"

Comment: The accepted answer is exactly what I meant to ask; if you have a better way to word the question then feel free to edit or let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put all your conditions as a `Func<bool>` into a list. Then via LINQ's `Count()` method you check how many of your conditions are true.

```
int x,y;

List<Func<bool>> yourConditions = new List<Func<bool>>
 {
  () => x < 4,
  () => y == 5,
  () => x + y > 7,
  // and so on...
 };

if(yourConditions.Count(condition => condition.Invoke() == true) >= 2)
 {
 // whatever you want to do
 }
```

If you have hundreds of conditions, this might not be very effective, because all conditions are evaluated. In that case, you can use the following:

```
if(yourCondition.Where(condition => condition.Invoke()).Skip(1).Any())
 {
 // whatever you want to do
 }
```

Now it will check only that many conditions until it found two conditions that are true.

Comment: Does this work? I think you have to invoke the delegates: `.Count(condition => condition() == true)`.